# Lack validation : Parameter exposed to external callers Python

Tags: python, fastapi

I run CodeGuru CodeReview in my project, I got following recommendation.

For this line : `return locale_alias[language][message]`

Problem: This line of code lacks validation when processing input data through the following parameter: 'message' (index: 1 | type: Unknown). The parameter is exposed to external callers, because its enclosing class and method are publicly accessible. This means that upstream validation, if it exists, can be bypassed. Other validated parameters: 'language'.Malicious, malformed, or unbounded inputs can cause unexpected runtime behavior or crashes, and can slow performance

Public method parameters should be validated for nullness, unexpected values, and malicious values. Invalid or malicious input can compromise the system's safety.

**Here is the code structure of my project.**

strings.py

```
TESTING_ME = "Testing language"
```

strings_fr.py

```
TESTING_ME = "French Testing language French"
```

strings_en.py

```
TESTING_ME = "English Testing language English"
```

string_class.py

```
import strings_handler    

# class to handle strings_handler based on message and language select from endpoint
class Locale:
    def __init__(self, language, message):
        self.string = strings_handler.select_locale(language, message)
```

strings_handler.py

```
  import strings as key

  def select_locale(language, message): 

      if language == "fr"  
          import strings_fr as strings
      else:
          import strings_en as strings
      locale_alias = {language:
        {key.TESTING_ME : strings.TESTING_ME }            
        }
      return locale_alias[language][message]
```

In api call

```
import Locale
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import APIRouter
router = APIRouter()

@router.post("/test")
async def test_program(language:Optional[str] = "en"):
     return JSONResponse(
        status_code=header_status,
        content={
            "message": Locale(language, strings.TESTING_ME).string
        }
    )
```

How to ensure the validity of parameters's value (message)?

Comment: What's your question? Can't you just put `if` statements to check if the parameters are keys in the dictionaries?

Comment: Can i have an example?

Comment: `if language in locale_alias and message in locale_alias[language]:`

Comment: ```if language in locale_alias and message in locale_alias[language]:
           self.string = strings_handler.select_locale(language, message)```
Like this in string_class.py

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Error - "'function' object has no attribute 'locale_alias'",

```if language in strings_handler.select_locale.locale_alias and message in strings_handler.select_locale.locale_alias.locale_alias[language]```

Comment: I have edited code for more clarificaton

Comment: Why are you writing `strings_handler.select_locale.locale_alias` instead of just `locale_alias`?

Comment: Why are you using the `language` parameter to create the dictionary? Isn't it something you should be looking up in an existing dictionary?

Comment: Using locale_alias gives ``` "message": "name 'locale_alias' is not defined",```
I have used language parameter to show message in user select language query . If user selects language "en" in query parameter of api , ```"English Testing language English"``` needs to be shown. If user selects langauge "fr" in query paramter of api,  ```"French Testing language French"``` is to be displayed. 

So , I set key as TESTING_ME.  
```Locale(language, strings.TESTING_ME).string```
```if lang is en  -->"English Testing language English"
if lang is fr -->  "French Testing language French"```

Comment: It's defined right there in the function: `locale_alias = {language:  {key.TESTING_ME : strings.TESTING_ME } }`. Are you trying to use it from a different function? Make it a global variable.

Comment: I defined locale_alias as global variable  then following error generated

``` Locale(
AttributeError: 'Locale' object has no attribute 'string'
```

Comment: No idea why that happens. You set the attribute with `self.string = strings_handler.select_locale(language, message)`